# Using Remote Desktop on my private VM, I enter another existing session than the previous one, depending on... my screen resolution?

Tags: centos, display, session, remote-desktop

At work, we are developing programs, each developer having his own private VM under *CentOS*.
I disconnect my session at the end of the day, then the next morning I start *Remote Desktop* under *Windows* and join it again.

But today, I went on a different *Windows* workstation, with lower resolution display.
I started my remote session with *Remote Desktop* as usual in direction of *CentOS* who led me to another, old, already opened session of mine that I started one month before...
I was troubled. I disconnected, came back to my previous workstation and retrieved the one I was expecting.

### Question 1 : How this behavior explains itself?

### Question 2 : How to drop my old session from the main one?

When I do a `who` command from my main session, I see myself + a number of me equals to the number of shell I have opened with *KConsole*.

How can I list how many others session like the one I found today are still opened and how can I close them?

Comment: Maybe `xrdp-sesadmin -c=list` will show your sessions if it's xrdp. Are you connecting to a server on your vm or is it something integrated into the vm software (like the built in vnc/spice in qemu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the xrdp settings (xrdp.ini or sessman.ini).

By default it will start a new session for earch new user and for each color resolution.

There are different settings which will cause different behaviours.

`pstree` will show your different sessions. All of them will propably be based on a window-manager. If you kill that father process from your active session you will terminate that other session.

`who am i` will show you your current session.